# How to declare a long long integer in c++?

Tags: c++, variables, declaration

what is this code bug? when I enter 50.000 , 50,000 it does not work.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a,b;
    long long int cost;
    cin>>a>>b;
    cost=a*b;
    cout<<cost;
}
```

Comment: *"it does not work."* - you can do better than that. What did you *expect* it to do to qualify as "working", and what is it *actually* doing that fails to meet those expectations ? Are you *really* entering a floating point 50.000 and a comma-separated 50 and 000 as your supposed *two* `int` input values (or at least trying to) ? If that really is your input, only `50` will make it into `a`. Everything else thereafter will fail, including populating `b`, because an `int` cannot start with `.`

Comment: Here's how to declare a long long integer in C++ `long long int cost;` Is that the question you meant to ask? If not then please state clearly what you actually want. Just saying *I want it to work* doesn't tell us anything. What do you want to work?

Comment: Please also take the [tour] and read [ask], to help improve your question.

Comment: @john I mean when I inter 50.000 and 50.000 as input the output is a negative and incorrect number , so I want to Know what is the bug; and I think its in declaration

Comment: @امیرمهدیهدایتی But what are you expecting it to do instead?

Comment: @امیرمهدیهدایتی The bug is definitely not in the declaration. The declaration is correct. But I cannot say what the bug is until I know what you are expecting to happen.

Comment: @امیرمهدیهدایتی What output are you expecting? It is not obvious.

Comment: @john I want it return me a true number that is 2,5*10^9

Comment: @امیرمهدیهدایتی Are you prepared to change the input? What happens if you enter `50000 50000`?

Comment: @john sorry . i found the bug when ew multiple a and b its return an common integer so it should be cost=a       cost=cost*b

Answer (score 1):

`a` and `b` are declared as `int`. The type of the result `a * b` is also `int`.
50000 * 50000 exceeds the capacity of an signed `int`. That bougous result will then be assigned to the `long long int` `cost`.

You need to declare `a` and `b` also as `long long int`, then the type of `a * b` will also be `long long int` and you won't see any problems, provided that the multiplication of `a` and `b` does not exceed the capacity of `long long int`, which still can happend here if you enter really large numbers.

Comment: better forget about long long int and `#include <cstdint>` and use `uint64_t`.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow `unint64_t` is only optionally available, while `long long int` is always available and wide enough to hold OPs numbers

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number If the compiler has long long int but not uint64_t it better be on a system without two's-complement, which practically doesn't exist. The only reason those types are optional is for hardware where the fundamental types don't exist. So if you find yourself on such a system it would be better to fix the include files.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow -- `long long` it is required to be **at least** 64 bits. It does not have to be **exactly** 64 bits. Making fixed-size types optional isn't about whether the integer types exist; it's about what size they are. C and C++ do not dictate absolute sizes, just minimum sizes. A C++ compiler that doesn't have a 64-bit integer type can be fully conforming: `long` could be 32 bits and `long long` could be 128 bits.

Comment: @PeteBecker So can be a compiler where char is 1024bit. But until you find a system that has 32bit and 128bit integers but no 64bit integer that is all just wishful thinking. On the other hand long long can indeed be 128 bit and long 64bit leading to a far too large type for 50000*50000 and wasteful code. If you really are afraid of a system having only 32bit and 128bit you could use uint_least64_t. Then you have the best of both worlds: A just large enough type for the problem without risk of 64bit not existing.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow -- it's not wishful thinking, nor is it fear; it's understanding the language definition. `long long` is the appropriate data type here; it's big enough and is required to exist. Forcing a particular size, absent an **explicit** requirement, is a design error; space isn't the only factor in choosing an integer type. `int`, `long`, and `long long` have the flexibility to be implemented efficiently on the target hardware; forced sizes do not.